# Best practices for cleaning up SQLAlchemy engine and sessionmaker instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

According to [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#session-faq-whentocreate), engine and sessionmaker instances should be created in the application's global scope:

> **When do I make a sessionmaker?** 
>  Just one time, somewhere in your application’s global scope. It should be looked upon as part of your application’s configuration. If your application has three .py files in a package, you could, for example, place the sessionmaker line in your __init__.py file; from that point on your other modules say “from mypackage import Session”. That way, everyone else just uses Session(), and the configuration of that session is controlled by that central point.

Questions:

1. What is the best practice for cleaning up SQLAlchemy engine and sessionmaker instances? Please refer to my example below, while I could call `engine.dispose()` in **main.py**, it does not seem a good practice to clean up a global object from a different module (**database.py**) in `__main__` (**main.py**), is there a better way to do it?
2. Do we need to clean up sessionmaker instances? It seems there is no method for closing the sessionmaker instance (`sessionmaker.close_all()` is deprecated, and `session.close_all_sessions()` is a session instance method and not sessionmaker method.)

Example:

- I created the engine and sessionmaker object in a module called **database.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager

DB_ENGINE = create_engine(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, pool_size=5, max_overflow=10)
DB_SESSION = sessionmaker(bind=DB_ENGINE, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, expire_on_commit=False)

@contextmanager
def db_session(db_session_factory):
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = db_session_factory()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

- In my main application **main.py**, I import the module and use the engine and sessionmaker instances as follows. I cleaned up the engine instance at the end of `__main__`.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from database import DB_ENGINE, DB_SESSION, db_session

def worker_func(data):
    with db_session(DB_SESSION) as session:
        [...database operations using session object...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        data = [1,2,3,4,5]
        with ThreadPool(processes=5) as thread_pool:
            results = thread_pool.map(worker_func, data)
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        # Cleanup
        DB_ENGINE.dispose()
```

Comment: Have you figure better way to write(best practices)

Comment: This question is WAYYY underrated. Hope someone experienced answers it!