# How do I produce a SQLAlchemy engine object and open a session at the start of an application without circular imports?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I'm creating a program to obtain data via API calls to store in a database and using a cronjob to have the application run every hour. If I understand SQLAlchemy correctly, I will need to create_engine() and open a session at the start of every run in order to run some of the queries.

I'm thinking about using this code:

```
def get_session():
    """Creates a new database session for instant use"""

    engine = create_engine(settings.DATASTORE_URI)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = scoped_session(Session)
    return (session, engine)
```

The only problem is I have 4 modules. 1 main module that will start the program and imports the functions and variables from the other 4 modules. If I put this function in the main function, then I can't import the session and engine for the 3 other modules that I have already coded because that would cause a circular import.

I've thought of some solutions:

1. create engine and session for every one of those modules
2. instantiate this in a class and use engine and session as parameters in each of the functions that I called.

Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same error, until I finally found my solution.

According to [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#session-faq-whentocreate), engine and sessionmaker instances should be created in the application's global scope:

> When do I make a sessionmaker? Just one time, somewhere in your
> application’s global scope. It should be looked upon as part of your
> application’s configuration. If your application has three .py files
> in a package, you could, for example, place the sessionmaker line in
> your **init**.py file; from that point on your other modules say “from
> mypackage import Session”. That way, everyone else just uses
> Session(), and the configuration of that session is controlled by that
> central point.

So in your scenario, what you need to do is:

- Keep your Main module, that will import the functions from all 4 other modules
- Keep your 4 function modules but you don't initiate the session or the engine in any of them
- Create a new file, where you create all the global variables, create the engine and start the session once.
- This new file will be imported into the 4 function modules. Your Main imports all the 4 function modules.

An example would be:

- new_file.py (with your engine, session and global variables)
- funcs1.py, funcs2.py, funcs3.py and funcs4.py (all of them imports new_file.py using `from new_file import *`)
- main.py (imports funcs1.py, funcs2.py, funcs3.py and funcs4.py using same import structure: `from XXXX import *`)

[Here is the reference that helped me a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337676/best-practices-for-cleaning-up-sqlalchemy-engine-and-sessionmaker-instances)